# Wordpress: How to turn page content into a popup

Tags: wordpress

I really appreciate your generosity in taking the time to help me out!

I am working on a portfolio site to showcase my graphic work on wordpress.

For most themes, when you click on a list item on the portfolio it directs  you to a new page dedicated to that item. I want it to be that when you click  on the link, a big popup (about half the screen) comes up that displays the contents.

Is there a way to make the page content into a popup? Is there a plugin I can use for this?

You can see what I am looking for in this site:http://www.mikekus.com/
When you click on the link for each item, it doesn't redirect you to a new page.  A popup comes up with the page information. How can I do that on wordpress?

Thank you in advance for your assistance!

Comment: Please do not use any plugins for such simple things! Create a div which is hidden. When a item has been clicked, use Ajax to load the content that you need into that div which is hidden and just show it then. That's it.

Answer (score 0):

Here is what that site is running on: [Dunked](https://dunked.com/).

There are [quite a few options](https://wordpress.org/plugins/search/post+popup+modal/) out there for this, especially in the WordPress plugin area. One fairly barebones looking one is [WP Post Popup](https://wordpress.org/plugins/wp-post-modal/) which, as the name implies, turns your posts into modal pop-up's instead of a new page.

Not sure if there is anything out of the box that is comparable to popping up on the side like the page you linked. With some CSS work though you could probably make the one I linked above, or any of them for that matter, look as you would like.

If you want to try and make something on your own, I would recommend doing some reading up on modal windows.